# How To Copy A Pre-existing Wordpress Site into a Local Environment

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

I'm trying to set up a local installation of a pre-existing Wordpress site (this is my first attempt ever). I'm using Xampp to run Apache and MySQL, and I have taken the WordPress files from the live site to my new directory INSIDE of `htdocs` folder from what I learned in this tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-setup-a-wordpress-development-environment-for-windows--wp-23365 ), but when I point the browser to http://localhost/wp-vs-423/ (I renamed the folder because I have the latest version of Wordpress - 4.2.3),

I get these errors:

> Warning: require_once(C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-load.php)
>   [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-blog-header.php on
>   line 12

and

> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening
>   required 'C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423/wp-load.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\webserver\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-blog-header.php on line 12

I see these files and the ones that I do not see I fish around for them on the web and end up grabbing them from GitHub or other places, even other Wordpress installs that I have.

I'm just not sure (and searching various facebook dev groups, googling for the past 4 or 5 days) about how to establish a local setup of a live WordPress site to test developments on it so as not to work on a live site. I do know that I was not able to clone the entire repository of the live site that I am working with, and I'm not sure if that is a problem or not. It seems that I am actually just missing some required Wordpress engine files, but how can I ascertain WHAT files I absolutely need, and where should they be living in the directory structure?

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Wordpress requires a database to work. That´s where it stores all data. Have you also exported and imported your WP database?

Comment: I have. Yes and my wp-config.php file is set to connect to it with the proper user name and password.

Comment: Perhaps change `.;C:\webserver\xampp\php\PEAR` to `C:\webserver\xampp\php\PEAR` in `C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-blog-header.php` on line `12`

Comment: this is all I have in the wp-blog-header.php
        <?php
        /**
       * Loads the WordPress environment and template.
       *
       * @package WordPress
       */

       if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

 $wp_did_header = true;

 require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

 wp();

 require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}

Comment: In your database in the wp_options (if using default names) table look for the siteurl and home fields and make sure their values are "http://localhost/wp-vs-423". Though I would advise the use of vhosts so you can make your local set up mimic a live server.

Comment: I do have that set in the database...but I still get the errors.

Answer (score 0):

try [the duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). copies the core, themes, plugins and database and uploads. easiest way i've found to move wordpress sites around

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've put the WordPress installation into a directory, which is relative and could cause issues. You might be better off using virtual hosts, or putting the files in your root web folder.

If that doesn't work, make sure in your database table `wp_options` there are two options 'siteurl' and 'home'. These need to be the local URL you'll use to access your site ie. `http://localhost/wp-vs-423` followed by a port if XAMP uses it.

I would take a look at setting up Virtual Hosts, and then creating entries in your Hosts file so then instead of using `localhost/your-directory` you can just use a single hostname such as `your-website.local`, which XAMP will treat as a normal URL, and more importantly, everything can be relative to it!

Comment: Thanks. I have all of that set up in the database, however I still get errors such as 
Warning: require(C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423/wp-includes/load.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-settings.php on line 19

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.;C:\webserver\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\webserver\xampp\htdocs\wp-vs-423\wp-settings.php on line 19

Virtual Hosts is not an option for me rigt now (I don't think)

Comment: It's because of the windows file path included with a web root url, see the mixture of forward and back slashes.

Comment: Yeah I saw that shortly after I posted it, but I have since corrected it and it still is not the cause. I'll go editing question.